# Help, my NVIDIA drivers are completely broken

Tags: 10.04, drivers, nvidia, video, graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and everything was fine up till about two hours ago, since when I've spent all my time trying to make things work again.  I was trying to install the latest drivers from the NVIDIA website, v285.05.09 (since I'm currently using the latest drivers available in Ubuntu, nvidia-current v195.36.24, yet WebGL doesn't work in either Chrome or Firefox, and they always suggest that I try the latest driver versions).

But after installing this and rebooting, X starts with an error, prompting me to run in reduced graphics mode and/or restore my graphics settings.  When I checked /var/log/kern.log I saw:

```
NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 285.05.09, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 195.36.24.  Please
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

My questions has two parts:

1. How do I actually make these latest NVIDIA drivers work?
2. If I try this out and it doesn't work...how do I roll back what I had before?  Here's what I tried, all to no avail:

   - picking the restore graphics settings option in the initial error prompt from X
   - under Administration > Hardware Drivers, I see that the "NVIDIA (current)" option is already chosen/active, so I can't do anything here
   - ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure nvidia-current`

**Update 1**: Some additional info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS
Release: 10.04
Codename: lucid

$ uname -a
Linux zs 2.6.32-35-generic #78-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 11 16:11:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii nvidia-173 173.14.22-0ubuntu11 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU li
ii nvidia-173-modaliases 173.14.22-0ubuntu11 Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver
ii nvidia-96-modaliases 96.43.17-0ubuntu1.1 Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver
ii nvidia-common 0.2.23 Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
ii nvidia-current 195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.1 NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU li
ii nvidia-current-modaliases 195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.1 Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver
ii nvidia-settings 195.36.08-0ubuntu2 Tool of configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

**Update 2**: Gyaaah!  I tried uninstalling my current drivers, rebooting, and installing the new drivers, but the drivers still aren't working. I still have to run X in reduced graphics mode, though now my resolution is no longer ridiculously low. Checking /var/log/kern.log for any lines mentioning "nouveau" or "NV":

```
...
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.935504] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.935512] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.939265] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected an NV50 generation card (0x450300a3)
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.939787] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Attempting to load BIOS image from PRAMIN
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.985378] input: HDA Digital PCBeep as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/input/input7
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998478] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: ... appears to be valid
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998483] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: BIT BIOS found
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998486] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Bios version 60.80.13.00
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998490] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: TMDS table revision 2.0 not currently supported
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998493] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: BIT table 'd' not found
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998495] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Found Display Configuration Block version 4.0
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998499] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DCB connector table: VHER 0x40 5 6 2
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998502] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0:   0: 0x00001030: type 0x30 idx 0 tag 0x07
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998506] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0:   1: 0x00002130: type 0x30 idx 1 tag 0x08
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998509] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0:   2: 0x00000210: type 0x10 idx 2 tag 0xff
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998511] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0:   3: 0x00000211: type 0x11 idx 2 tag 0xff
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998514] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0:   4: 0x00000213: type 0x13 idx 2 tag 0xff
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998517] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Raw DCB entry 0: 04000320 00000028
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998520] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Raw DCB entry 1: 01000322 00000030
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998523] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Raw DCB entry 2: 02011310 00000028
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998525] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Raw DCB entry 3: 02011312 00000030
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998528] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Raw DCB entry 4: 010223f1 00c1c020
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   29.998537] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table 0 at offset 0xBC7E
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.050942] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table 1 at offset 0xBE86
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.120749] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table 2 at offset 0xD041
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.120764] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table 3 at offset 0xD130
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.140789] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table 4 at offset 0xD2E7
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.140795] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Parsing VBIOS init table at offset 0xD34C
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.170875] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0xD34C: Condition still not met after 20ms, skipping following opcodes
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.170906] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0xAF80: parsing output script 0
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.170912] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0xAF80: parsing output script 0
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.170916] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0xA64E: parsing output script 0
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.254497] type=1505 audit(1320954803.872:10):  operation="profile_replace" pid=852 name="/sbin/dhclient3"
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.255310] type=1505 audit(1320954803.872:11):  operation="profile_replace" pid=852 name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action"
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.305204] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 1027826 kiB.
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.305217] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 640 MiB VRAM
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.327746] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 512 MiB GART (aperture)
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.329065] mtrr: type mismatch for c0000000,10000000 old: write-back new: write-combining
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.329664] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Allocating FIFO number 1
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334438] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: nouveau_channel_alloc: initialised FIFO 1
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334987] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a DAC output
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334990] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a TMDS output
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334993] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a DAC output
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334995] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a TMDS output
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.334998] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DCB encoder 1 unknown
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.335002] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a DVI-I connector
Nov 10 11:53:23 zs kernel: [   30.335629] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Detected a DVI-I connector
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.528555] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: allocated 1680x1050 fb: 0x40250000, bo ffff880058a91000
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.528735] fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.528738] registered panic notifier
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.528746] [drm] Initialized nouveau 0.0.15 20090420 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.540435] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 27 for MSI/MSI-X
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.570248] input: HDA Intel Line In at Ext Rear Jack as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
Nov 10 11:53:24 zs kernel: [   30.570358] input: HDA Intel Mic at Ext Front Jack as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
...
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   31.668292] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   31.668296] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317525] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317529] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317531] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317532] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317535] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317536] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317537] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317538] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.317540] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.358823] [drm] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: 0x0F8F: parsing clock script 0
Nov 10 11:53:25 zs kernel: [   32.359228] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 210x65
Nov 10 11:53:26 zs kernel: [   33.071512] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Nov 10 11:53:26 zs kernel: [   33.071822] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479454] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479458] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479460] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479461] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479464] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479465] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479466] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479467] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:29 zs kernel: [   35.479469] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436692] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436697] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436698] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436700] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436702] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436703] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436704] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436706] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   36.436708] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336097] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336102] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336103] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336104] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336107] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336108] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336109] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336110] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:30 zs kernel: [   37.336113] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.180042] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185035] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185039] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185040] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185041] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185044] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185045] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185046] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185047] NVRM: again.

Nov 10 11:53:31 zs kernel: [   38.185049] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085538] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085542] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085544] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085545] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085547] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085549] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085550] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085551] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:32 zs kernel: [   39.085553] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892052] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892056] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892058] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892059] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892062] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892063] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892064] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892065] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:33 zs kernel: [   39.892067] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695893] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine was not called for 1 device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695896] NVRM: This can occur when a driver such as nouveau, rivafb,
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695898] NVRM: nvidiafb, or rivatv was loaded and obtained ownership of
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695899] NVRM: the NVIDIA device(s).
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695902] NVRM: Try unloading the conflicting kernel module (and/or
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695903] NVRM: reconfigure your kernel without the conflicting
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695904] NVRM: driver(s)), then try loading the NVIDIA kernel module
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695905] NVRM: again.
Nov 10 11:53:34 zs kernel: [   40.695907] NVRM: No NVIDIA graphics adapter probed!
...
```

I tried uninstalling `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` (and hence `xserver-xorg-video-all`), but that didn't do anything.

Here's all I have left installed:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-173-modaliases                                                        173.14.22-0ubuntu11                             Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver
ii  nvidia-96-modaliases                                                         96.43.17-0ubuntu1.1                             Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver
ii  nvidia-common                                                                0.2.23                                          Find obsolete NVIDIA drivers
ii  nvidia-current-modaliases                                                    195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.1                      Modaliases for the NVIDIA binary X.Org driver

$ aptitude search nouveau
i   libdrm-nouveau1                 - Userspace interface to nouveau-specific ke
p   libdrm-nouveau1-dbg             - Userspace interface to nouveau-specific ke
p   nouveau-firmware                - Firmware for nVidia graphics cards        
p   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau      - X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver (
```

Last bit of info on drivers:

```
$ lspci -v
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G80 [GeForce 8800 GTS] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: nVidia Corporation Device 0421
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at dc000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at dc80 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at dfe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidia, nvidiafb, nouveau

$ lsmod | egrep 'nouveau|nvidia'
nouveau               515227  3 
ttm                    61039  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         30742  1 nouveau
drm                   200288  3 nouveau,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            6024  1 nouveau
```

**Update 3**: Guess I should also note by now that this is on a *desktop*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to deactivate the drivers under *additional drivers* prior to instal the new ones. Go to the *additional drivers* application, deactivate the **nvidia current** drivers, reboot and install the drivers from the nvidia site as you did before.

Comment: I followed your instructions (deactivated the current drivers, rebooted, and installed the new drivers), but the drivers are still not working. I've updated my question with more information.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*` to remove all packages from nvidia, try to install the 285 after this.

Comment: After doing that plus more fidgeting (at some point the NVIDIA installer started prompting me to install a modprobe.d file that would disable nouveau - I think this was key), everything just started working with 285. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome! gl and if they break again drop a comment on the same question ;)